# How to find the inverse position inside a triangle

Tags: triangles

If I were standing in a equilateral triangle - How do I calculate the inverse of my position? Can it be done? It's easy inside a rectangle, but I can't think of how you would do it inside of a triangle.

For instance if I'm in one corner of a rectangle, I know the inverse of my position is the opposite corner. But with a triangle it is different. I suspect there must be a way to calculate an inverse, or maybe just the farthest point from any given point.

I'm working on a color theory in case it matters.

Comment: Inverse of position?

Comment: Ah, you could use some transformation, like *rotating* $120^\circ$ around the center.. Is it a *regular triangle* at all? Or you can use *reflections* to a midline.. what would you prefer?

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

This question is quite hard to answer, because we aren't provided with a satisfying definition of "inverse of a position". So in order for my answer to make sense I wil first have to introduce a definition. I will do this for a very general case, namely: for the boundary $\partial S$ of an $n$-dimenstional convex set $S$ in the Eucledian space $\mathbb R^n$. In the OP for example, $\partial S$ is a triangle.

> Consider a point $x\in \partial S$ and any point $P\in\mathring S$. The inverse point of $x$ with respect to $P$ is now defined as the intesection between $\partial S$ and the line through $x$ and $P$, (which is not $x$ itself). Notation: $\mathfrak I_P(x)$.

The map $\mathfrak I_P:\partial S\to \partial S$ is now well-defined due to the convexness. It can even be extended to the whole of $\bar S$ in a very obvious  way.

So loosely speaking, we are reflecting in the point $P$. Any interior point $P$ will do in fact.

In the OP's case we are considering an equilateral triangle. Now an equilateral triangle has one particular nice point (opinion based), which is of course its incentre. So a very natural choise would be to choose this point for $P$.

---

This somewhat answers the question, however as with any definition, the OP is free to make another one that suites his needs better. The most important thing for the OP to know is that the "inverse of a position" has no conventional definion in general. So in any such case one must make their own definition, check that it is well-defined and that is usefull.